# User sign in for popular mobile apps and session management

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm in process of developing a mobile app using `Ionic` framework for Android. In process of development, I came across couple of questions:

1. I'm building a `SignUp`/`SignIn` page, in case if the user is not registered, he will register and if already registered then user will login. Once when the user is logged in and if user close the app and come back, he is still logged in, how is that maintained?
2. for ex: like Amazon, when the user add some items to cart and close the app, cart is retained even when user re opens the app. Is it like, server should store such information or how can that be achieved?

Please suggest, thanks in advance.

Comment: The cart shouldn't precisely need to be logged in to maintain item except online. Amazon app however must use WebView or equivalent as they cannot locally provide everything and hence the cart is always online. So they can have login such as a token, or whatever. Password and username are probably stored securely and then can also be re-used if needed as user doesn't have to re-enter these items.

Comment: Basically, user name and password are stored on client side (like app storage (or) local db)? Could you please elaborate on webview part?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the session token after logging in and use it when logging on to the application.
During the launch of the application, you simply need to check whether the token is saved, if not, then open the login page.

Comment: So basically, whenever we open the app, we need to check the validity of the token. I believe most of the apps mask this feature as i have not logged in again after first time login. May be they are storing this in local DB and every time when the app is opened, they check this token logic (and mask the login). This is what I am guessing